# FactoryGirl, Rspec, let, and before issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using some of these tools for the first time. I have read through the docs but wanted to ask here exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a set of users that I want to test some actions I can do in a controller spec. When each user is created, there are a set of callbacks that take place to create associated objects.

I'd like to have access to these user instances and the associated objects of that ActiveRecord class. So for example, a user will have a set of lists so I'd like to be able to  call user1.lists for example.

Also, I'd like to isolate this setup at the top and use either let's or a before black. It seems that just calling let like this:

```
# will test that get_count_for_list will return 5
describe ApiController do

  # why same name - seems really confusing!
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user2) }
```

doesn't call the associated callbacks. Is this correct? Or is it possibly a timing issue?

I like the syntax of using let and being able to access these objects in my ExampleGroups such as user.id but can't access user.lists. Currently I am doing something like:

```
# will test that get_count_for_list will return 5

describe ApiController do

  # why same name - seems really confusing!
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user2) }
  let(:user3) { FactoryGirl.create(:user3) }
  
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user2)
    FactoryGirl.create(:user3)
  end
```

but feel that there has to be a better way. Am I creating these user's twice?

thx

### edit 1

I've isolated the code in question here. The global_id value is created via a callback. It exists correctly in the db and can be accessed via the corresponding find_by_email's but using the user2 var's doesn't provide access.

```
require 'spec_helper'

# will test that get_count_for_list will return 5
describe ApiController do
  # why same name - seems really confusing!
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user2) }
  let!(:user3) { FactoryGirl.create(:user3) }


  
  before do
    session[:user_id]=user.id # works
  end

  describe 'FOLLOW / UNFOLLOW options' do
    it 'shall test the ability to follow another user' do
      puts "user1: " + user.global_id.to_s # doesn't output anything
      u2=User.find_by_email('jo@jo.com') # corresponds to user2
      post :follow, :global_id => user2.global_id # doesn't work
      #post :follow, :global_id => u2.global_id  #works


      u3=User.find_by_email('su@su.com')
      puts "user_3" + u3.global_id.to_s # outputs correct value

      post :follow, :global_id => user3.global_id  #doesn't work
      #post :follow, :global_id => u3.global_id # works


      post :unfollow, :global_id => user.following.sample(1)
      response.code.should eq('200')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the rspec doc: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the method's invocation before each example.

In other words if you use `let` along with `factory_girl` a record will not be created before let-variable invocation.

The correct code is:

```
# will test that get_count_for_list will return 5
describe ApiController do

  # why same name - seems really confusing!
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user2) }
```

Comment: so I've included the code above in edit 1 - perhaps when you say lazy evaluated, you mean something different from what I'm thinking. But I still don't have access to these callback values event with let!. I think the above code should work of accessing these factories like this. Is there possibly some other syntax issues I'm not aware of.

Comment: thx for answer. sorry - but the edits look like the same as what I have in edit #1 (realize times are about the same). thx for any further clarification

Comment: I don't get this.  The dev shouldn't have to create a new factory just so he can `let` a variable of the same name (e.g. `:user2`).

Answer (score 3):

I just solved a similar sounding problem. My user authentication spec was not passing using 'let'.

my broken spec:

```
describe "signin" do
  before { visit signin_path }

  describe "with valid information", :js => true do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      fill_in "email", with: user.email
      fill_in "password", with: user.password
      click_button "Log In"
    end
    it { should have_selector('a', text: "#{user.first} #{user.last}") }
  end
end
```

This was not working. The log-in authentication was failing as if the user record was not actually in the database when my sessions controller tries to authenticate it. I tried replacing let with let! but that did not fix anything. Reading this post, and the link above explaining let and let! I realized that I should not be using let for this spec. Now I have a passing spec:

```
describe "signin" do
  before { visit signin_path }

  describe "with valid information", :js => true do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    before do
      fill_in "email", with: user.email
      fill_in "password", with: user.password
      click_button "Log In"
    end
    it { should have_selector('a', text: "#{user.first} #{user.last}") }
  end
end
```